Websocket client closing when server sends data
I'm trying to set up a websocket connection in React app using react-use-websocket   library. I was recommended to use WebSocketContext and WebSocketProvider architecture to wrap my child components:
  <WebSocketProvider>
            <ClientComponent/>
              <WebSocketProvider>

This is my websocket context code:
// WebSocketContext.tsx
import React, { createContext, useContext, useEffect } from 'react';
import useWebSocket from 'react-use-websocket';
import useToken from '../../app/use-token';
import { useState } from 'react';

interface WebSocketContextProps {
  sendMessage: (msg: string) => void;
  lastMessage: MessageEvent | null;
  readyState: number;
}

const WebSocketContext = createContext<WebSocketContextProps | undefined>(undefined);

export const useWebSocketContext = () => {
  const context = useContext(WebSocketContext);
  if (!context) {
    throw new Error('useWebSocketContext must be used within a WebSocketProvider');
  }
  return context;
};

export const WebSocketProvider: React.FC<{ children: React.ReactNode }> = ({ children }) => {
  const { token } = useToken();
  const [isWebSocketInitialized, setIsWebSocketInitialized] = useState(false);

  // Initialize WebSocket connection only if token is not null and WebSocket is not already initialized
  const { sendMessage, lastMessage, readyState } = useWebSocket(
    token && !isWebSocketInitialized ? 'ws://localhost:8003/ws' : null,
    {
      onOpen: () => {
        console.log('WebSocket opened');
        if (token) {
          sendMessage(token); // Send token once WebSocket opens
          setIsWebSocketInitialized(true); // Mark WebSocket as initialized
        } else {
          console.error('Token is null');
        }
      },
      onClose: () => {
        console.log('WebSocket closed');
      },
      onMessage: (event) => {
        console.log('Message received:', event.data);
      },
      onError: (event) => console.error('WebSocket error:', event),
      shouldReconnect: (closeEvent) => false, // Enable automatic reconnect
    }
  );

  // Handle incoming messages
  useEffect(() => {
    if (lastMessage !== null) {
      console.log('Message received:', lastMessage.data); // Access the 'data' field here
    } else {
      console.log('No message received');
    } 

  }, [lastMessage]);
  

  return (
    <WebSocketContext.Provider value={{ sendMessage, lastMessage, readyState }}>
      {children}
    </WebSocketContext.Provider>
  );
};


which i set to send a token after connecting for auth purposes. The token is sent just fine as i see in webscoket server, but as soon as the client sents a message, connection is closed and server receives this message: received: {'type': 'websocket.disconnect', 'code': <CloseCode.NO_STATUS_RCVD: 1005>}.
My client uses python FastAPI Websocket and i have used it with other clients and works fine. I think the problem could be in client websocket provider.
Can someone say what am i missing?
I am trying to set a long-lived connection between React app and Websocket server, but it is closed immediatly after connecting.

Does this answer your question? This might help as well.
